# Unable to understand edits

Tags: support, edits

I'm unable to understand this.

Someone edited my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976142/complex-calculator-without-using-the-basic-formula/27976251#27976251).

My edit was, literally deleting all of my answer, and the comment is "save changes..". What does it mean to save changes? How can I save changes if they have got to be changed? How can I know which user has edited me, so I can ask more information about the edit he just did?

I'm still new to all these things, and I think my answer is right, and well explained (also the one who makes the question thanked me for it and "checked" it).

Do I reject the edit, or is there any "unwritten" code of conduct between users on Stack Overflow that I just trespassed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's OK to reject an edit you don't agree with. If it messed it up that bad probably it was either someone trolling or maybe even the person who asked the question trying to reply that way in error.

Comment: Regarding "My edit was": Don't you mean "The other user's edit was" (or similar)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As the OP of that answer, you are completely welcome to reject edits that change the answer into something you don't want associated with your account. I've done it multiple times.

If the edit is made and approved *before* you see it, you can roll it back from the post's revision history. That's also not frowned upon.

Comment: I upvote you, thanks for the edit in my question.